# Is it possible to append to a nested array from within an outer layer of that array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php

$x = array
(
    'test' => array('asd', 'works'),
    'blah' => $x['test'] + array('more')
);

print_r($x);
?>
```

Basically, is it possible for 'blah' to have the contents of 'test'?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the circular way you have. However, you could do the following to achieve the desired result.

```
$x = array
(
    'test' => array('asd', 'works')
);

$x['blah'] = $x['test'];
array_push($x['blah'], 'more');

print_r($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it while declaring the array.

however, you can assign the same values with a different key.